# Difficulties to make a service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, service

I am new in angularJS, and I tried to make a service to handle HTTP requests.

So here is my service :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['base64']);

/* Main controller
================================================== */

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "HTTPrequest",
    function($scope, HTTPrequest) {
        $scope.data = HTTPrequest.getAllVideos();
    }
]);

/* Service which handles HTTP requests
================================================== */

app.service("HTTPrequest", [ "$http", "$base64",
    function($http, $base64) {

        //Getter pour la variable videos
        this.getAllVideos = function($http, $base64) {

            // Authentification for HTTP request on RESTHeart server
            $http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Basic ' + $base64.encode("LOGIN" + ":" + "PASSWORD");

            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'http://localhost/db/videos',
            }).then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                var videos = response.data;
                return videos;
                },
                function errorCallback(response) {

                }
              );

        };

    }
]);
```

And in my Chrome console I have this error which refers to the Authentification line :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

I succeed to do my request without service, but impossible to reproduce with a service :(

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.getAllVideos = function($http, $base64) {
```

to

```
this.getAllVideos = function() {
```

You don't want to pass any argument when getting the videos. And the $http and $base64 services are injected in the service constructor function.

You also forgot to return from your function. Replace

```
$http({
```

by

```
return $http({
```

And once that is done, replace

```
$scope.data = HTTPrequest.getAllVideos();
```

by

```
HTTPrequest.getAllVideos().then(function(videos) {
    $scope.data = videos;
});
```

You should also remove the empty eror callback from the $http call. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/, because you're falling into many promise traps.

Comment: Thank you, it resolves the problem. I haven't the error any more. I don't have my result but it might come from else where !

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit, it works !! I still have difficulties to understand angularJS  philosophy ... (Merci puisque français ;) )